# How connect two or more subscribers in Jedis(Java Redis)?

Tags: java, multithreading, redis, jedis

I have two subscribers which should connect to different channels. But if I try subscribe them to channels nothing happens. I think that it is some multithreading problem but have not any idea how solve this problem. Is there any example for how to work with multiple subscribers?

Comment: could you share your code where you connect to different channels and what do you mean by nothing happens?Are you sure that your redis server is publishing something to the channels you are connecting to?

Answer (score 1):

If it is not under race condition, https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/pull/998 can help you, and it's scheduled to be released at next version.

Btw, if you don't need to subscribe dynamically, or your channels has same pattern, you don't need to create subscriber for each channel. You can use Jedis.subscribe() and Jedis.psubscribe() to subscribe multiple channel at once.

You can handle messages from onMessage() which gives you channel name and message.